# XML Document is empty Made from PHP

Tags: php, xml, http-headers

Im trying to make a xml document with PHP.

But when I try to do that I get the following error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

My source:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

print(htmlentities('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bbcodes>
<block>
<pattern><![CDATA[<p.*?>]]></pattern>
<replace><![CDATA[[p]]]></replace>
</block>
<block>
<pattern><![CDATA[</p>]]></pattern>
<replace><![CDATA[[/p]]]></replace>
</block>
</bbcodes>'));

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `htmlentities`? It'll convert XML to text!

Comment: I though that should be used to get the right output. But I was wrong I see now. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same error with your code. When I remove the htmlentities function, it works just fine.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

print('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bbcodes>
<block>
<pattern><![CDATA[<p.*?>]]></pattern>
<replace><![CDATA[[p]]]></replace>
</block>
<block>
<pattern><![CDATA[</p>]]></pattern>
<replace><![CDATA[[/p]]]></replace>
</block>
</bbcodes>');

?>
```